# Cloning a div with content doesn't work somehow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have another div where it does work with this js code but somehow with this one it doesnt. Can anyone tell me why it doesnt work?

```
$(function () {
    var $scntDiv = $('#parts');
    var i = $('#parts input').size()-1;

    $('#addField').on('click', function () {
        var part = '<div id="parts' + i + '"><span>Part</span> <input type="text" id="auto_part' + i + '" name="auto_part' + i + '" /><br/>' +
            '<span>Description</span> <textarea type="text" id="auto_description' + i + '" name="auto_description' + i + '"></textarea> <br />' +
            '<a href="#" class="removefield">Remove</a></div>';
        $scntDiv.after(part);
        $("#row_count").val(i);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".removefield", function () {
        if (i > 2) {
            $("#row_count").val(i-2);
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});

$(function () {
    var $scntDiv = $('.brands');
    var i = $('.brands select').size()-1;

    $('#addBrand').on('click', function () {
        var brand = "<div class='brands'><span>Brands</span><br />"+
            '<select>'+
                '<option>Audi</option>'+
                '<option>BMW</option>'+
                '<option>Mercedes</option>'+
            '</select>'+
        '</div>';
        $scntDiv.after(brand);
        $("#countBrand").val(i);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".removeBrand", function () {
        if (i > 2) {
            $("#countBrand").val(i-2);
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

The first function works for me but the last one doesn't.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rEUPx/

Comment: Your demo miss jQuery.

Comment: You did this on your last question. You don't have jQuery loaded. I told you that, and you deleted your question. So I'll tell  you again, you need to load jQuery before you can use it. It''s not omnipresent. It's a code library that is useless when absent. Choose one of the jQuery options from the menu on the left.

Comment: I'm out of votes for today, but this should be closed as "too localized". Learn how to use jsfiddle.

Comment: I do have jqeury included in my own script but it still doesnt work there while other jquery things do work

Comment: @Sinan: So the fiddle works as you expect but your code doesn't? You never explained your problem properly. Since we don't know anything about your actual code, we cannot really help you there. If the fiddle works as you expect, make sure you have the same in your actual code.

Comment: Yes somehow it does work with fiddle now with jquery included, but it still doesnt in my code while its the exact same code. I editting my code sec

Comment: @Sinan: Well, we cannot really help you there. The code you posted works fine. So it must be a problem with the code you *didn't* post. But since we don't know anything about it, we cannot do anything about it.

Comment: Even when I put the whole code in it it works with jsfiddle but it doesnt in my code... http://jsfiddle.net/rEUPx/10/

Comment: I encourage you to **really** describe your problem. "It does not work" is not an useful error description. And again, we cannot help you if we cannot reproduce the problem. It's a simple as that.

Comment: I understand. But it just doesnt do anything. Nothing in the console either. When I click on the add button it just scrolls back up to the page.

Answer (score -1):

Two things, you must add your jQuery to the page, and replace the inner double quotes of the js string with single quotes and make the outer quotes double.

http://jsfiddle.net/rEUPx/4/

`var a = '<a href="#">CLICK</a>'; // will result in an error`

`var a = "<a href='#'>CLICK</a>"; // is correct`

Comment: Thanks, this one does help unlike the comments on my question :P

Comment: lol but they were right! you didn't use fiddle correctly :) and that was just a syntax error nothing major

Comment: This is incorrect. `'<a href="#">CLICK</a>'` is the same as `"<a href='#'>CLICK</a>"`. Both are correct. Why do you say it is a syntax error? This is the OP's code **with only jQuery included** and it works perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/rEUPx/5/.

Comment: @Sinan: So you find made up things more helpful? The only mistake you made was not including jQuery and that was pointed out in the comments. What more do you expect?

Comment: Lol it doesnt work indeed I just noticed and im still fkin with it any in my script jquery is included ofcourse I thought jsfiddle had it included. But yea it still doesnt work for me. How does his jsfiddle work then anyway..

Comment: @Sinan: So the fiddle works as you expect but your code doesn't? You never explained your problem properly.

Comment: Yes somehow it does work with fiddle now with jquery included, but it still doesnt in my code while its the exact same code.